# Every singe field can be edited except the DateTime. Always resets to defaut - MVC ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm creating MVC ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web App. Please find the code....

ApplicationUser.cs class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

ProfileModel.cs view class:

```
public class ProfileModel
{
    ...

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM.dd.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Segment from AppUserService.cs class responsible for updating user info:

```
public async Task UpdateUserInfo(string id, string firstName, string lastName, string email, DateTime birthDate, string country)
    {
        var user = GetById(id);
        user.Email = email;
        user.FirstName = firstName;
        user.LastName = lastName;
        user.DateOfBirth = birthDate;
        user.Country = country;
        _context.Update(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Segment from ProfileController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string firstName, string lastName, string email, DateTime birthDate, string country)
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

        await _userService.UpdateUserInfo(userId, firstName, lastName, email, birthDate, country);

        return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Profile", new { id = userId });
    }
```

In the view Detail.cshtml there is a part which displays the birth date

```
<dt>Date of birth:/dt>
<dd>
    Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.DateOfBirth)
</dd>
```

and this is the birth date edit part in modal window

```
<div class="ProfileInput">
    <input type="text" asp-for="DateOfBirth" placeholder=" " />
    <div class="ProfileInputUnderline"></div>
    <label>Date of Birth</label>
</div>
```

As shown in the picture below, I can edit all properties except the DateOfBirth. Every property gets updated, but DateOfBirth always resets to the default value.
What am I missing? I would really appreciate your help.

[image: View image]

Comment: I suspect the model binder is unable to understand the `MM.dd.yyyy` format. Dates are usually expected to be sent to the server using `yyyy-MM-dd`, which is what an `<input type="date">` would send. You may need to use a custom model binder for your dates.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Even when I remove the annotation (or set it to `yyyy-MM-dd`) and change `<input type="text">` to `<input type="date">`, it doesn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem: your input is defined with `asp-for="DateOfBirth"`, but your action parameter is called `birthDate`.

The quick-and-dirty solution is to rename your action parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string firstName, string lastName, string email, DateTime dateOfBirth, string country)
{
    var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

    await _userService.UpdateUserInfo(userId, firstName, lastName, email, dateOfBirth, country);

    return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Profile", new { id = userId });
}
```

The better option would be to change your `POST` method to take a `ProfileModel` parameter instead, which would prevent this sort of mis-match from happening again:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(ProfileModel model)
{
    var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

    await _userService.UpdateUserInfo(userId, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Email, model.DateOfBirth, model.Country);

    return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Profile", new { id = userId });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking at the code for several hours.